# How to redirect console output in IZPack

Tags: redirect, izpack

Can anyone please tell me how can we redirect the console output to a file or something else.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

there's a section in IzPack's documentation (**[Here](http://izpack.org/documentation/advanced-features.html#logging-the-installation)**) that lists various areas that can be logged, namely: Debug Info, Summary of Panels, Installed File Set, Process Panel, Ant Actions.

`process panel:` [-Link-](http://izpack.org/documentation/panels.html#logfiledir-output-of-the-processpanel-saved-to-a-log)
`ant actions:` [-Link-](http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html#the-basic-xml-struture)
`debug info:` [-Link1-](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/izpack-user/4nP-2DjOiBQ) or the `Debug class` @[-Link2-](http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-util/apidocs/com/izforge/izpack/util/Debug.html), to set the log file/location.
`summary panel:` [-Link-](http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html#summary-logger-installerlistener)